# Building Bochs using CygWin: "no rule to make target"

Tags: shell, command-line, compilation, makefile, cygwin

I'm building **Bochs** from source using CygWin.

## What I've already done:

1. Changing the value of my `$PATH` variable in order to use CygWin's `find` instead of Windows' `find`: `PATH='/cygdrive/c/Programme/cygwin/bin':${PATH}`
2. **Configuring**: Exceution of my configure script (see below): `./.conf.my-win32-vcpp`
3. **Building** via `make win32_snap`
4. **Installing** via `make install` **(not successfully)**

## My question:

How can I build and install Bochs from source (without having these problems)? Any idea?

Thanks.

## My configure script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set echo

./configure --target=pentium-windows \
            --enable-sb16 \
            --enable-ne2000 \
            --enable-all-optimizations \
            --enable-cpu-level=6 \
            --enable-x86-64 \
            --enable-pci \
            --enable-clgd54xx \
            --enable-usb \
            --enable-usb-ohci \
            --enable-show-ips \
            --enable-disasm \
            --enable-iodebug \
            --enable-logging \
            --enable-debugger-gui \
            --disable-readline \
            --without-x \
            --with-win32 \
            --with-rfb \
            --with-nogui \
            --with-wx

unset echo

# Fix up all makefiles so that nmake can handle them.
for i in `find . -name Makefile`; do
  echo Removing curly brackets in $i for NMAKE.
  mv $i $i.tmp
  sed -e 's/{/(/g' -e 's/}/)/g' < $i.tmp > $i
  rm -f $i.tmp
done
```

## The error messages:

While I run my configure script (`./.conf.my-win32-vcpp`), I got some warnings, but it executed successfully:

```
[...]
configure: WARNING: pthread.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: pthread.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: pthread.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: pthread.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: pthread.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
[...]
```

And there wasn't any problem while evaluating `make win32_snap`. But when I try to `make install`, `Error 2` occurs:

```
cd iodev
C:/gnuwin/make  libiodev.a
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/JK/Downloads/bochs-2.5.1'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `libiodev.a'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/JK/Downloads/bochs-2.5.1'
make: *** [iodev/libiodev.a] Error 2
```

## My environment:

I use **CygWin**'s `sh` shell on Win64.
My `$PATH`:

> `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft
>   Shared/Windows Live:` *(...)* `:/cygdrive/c/prog-x86/MinGW/bin:`
>   *(...)* `:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32` *(...)*
>   `:/cygdrive/c/gnuwin:/usr/bin` *(...)*

I'm using GnuWin's `make`:

```
sh-4.1$ type make
make is hashed (/cygdrive/c/gnuwin/make)
```

## My directory tree:

#### Folders:

```
sh-4.1$ tree -d
.
|-- bios
|-- build
|   |-- linux
|   |-- macos
|   |-- macosx
|   |-- redhat
|   `-- win32
|       `-- nsis
|-- bx_debug
|-- cpu
|   `-- cpudb
|-- disasm
|-- doc
|   |-- docbook
|   |   |-- development
|   |   |-- documentation
|   |   |-- images
|   |   |-- include
|   |   `-- user
|   `-- man
|-- docs-html
|-- fpu
|-- gui
|   |-- bitmaps
|   |-- font
|   `-- keymaps
|-- host
|   `-- linux
|       `-- pcidev
|-- instrument
|   |-- example0
|   |-- example1
|   |-- example2
|   `-- stubs
|-- iodev
|-- memory
|-- misc
|   `-- sb16
|-- patches
`-- vs2008

40 directories
```

#### Files:

```
sh-4.1$ tree
.
|-- CHANGES
|-- COPYING
|-- Makefile
|-- Makefile.in
|-- PARAM_TREE.txt
|-- README
|-- README-plugins
|-- README-wxWindows
|-- README.rfb
|-- TESTFORM.txt
|-- TODO
|-- aclocal.m4
|-- bios
|   |-- BIOS-bochs-latest
|   |-- BIOS-bochs-legacy
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- Makefile.in
|   |-- VGABIOS-elpin-2.40
|   |-- VGABIOS-elpin-LICENSE
|   |-- VGABIOS-lgpl-README
|   |-- VGABIOS-lgpl-latest
|   |-- VGABIOS-lgpl-latest-cirrus
|   |-- VGABIOS-lgpl-latest-cirrus-debug
|   |-- VGABIOS-lgpl-latest-debug
|   |-- acpi-dsdt.dsl
|   |-- acpi-dsdt.hex
|   |-- apmbios.S
|   |-- bios_usage
|   |-- biossums.c
|   |-- makesym.perl
|   |-- notes
|   |-- rombios.c
|   |-- rombios.h
|   |-- rombios32.c
|   |-- rombios32.ld
|   |-- rombios32start.S
|   `-- usage.cc
|-- bochs.h
|-- build
|   |-- batch-build.perl
|   |-- linux
|   |   |-- README.linux-binary
|   |   |-- bochs-dlx
|   |   `-- bochs-dlx.in
|   |-- macos
|   |   |-- CWPro3_project.sit
|   |   |-- bochs.rsrc
|   |   |-- bochsico.bmp
|   |   `-- macos_defines.h
|   |-- macosx
|   |   |-- Info.plist
|   |   |-- Info.plist.in
|   |   |-- README.macosx-binary
|   |   |-- bochs-icn.icns
|   |   |-- bochs.applescript
|   |   |-- bochs.r
|   |   |-- diskimage.pl
|   |   |-- make-dmg.sh
|   |   |-- pbdevelopment.plist
|   |   |-- script.data
|   |   `-- script.r
|   |-- makeall.sh
|   |-- redhat
|   |   |-- NOTES
|   |   |-- bochs.rpmspec.template
|   |   `-- make-rpm
|   `-- win32
|       |-- README.win32-binary
|       |-- bochs.manifest
|       |-- cc2cpp
|       |-- cpp2cc
|       |-- diffcc2cpp
|       |-- nsis
|       |   |-- Makefile
|       |   |-- Makefile.in
|       |   |-- bochs.ico
|       |   |-- bochs.nsi
|       |   |-- bochs.nsi.in
|       |   |-- lgban.ico
|       |   |-- logo.ico
|       |   |-- penguin.ico
|       |   `-- unbochs.ico
|       |-- vs2008ex-plugins-workspace.zip
|       `-- vs2008ex-workspace.zip
|-- bx_debug
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- Makefile.in
|   |-- dbg_main.cc
|   |-- debug.h
|   |-- lexer.c
|   |-- lexer.l
|   |-- linux.cc
|   |-- make-syscalls-linux.pl
|   |-- parser.c
|   |-- parser.h
|   |-- parser.y
|   |-- symbols.cc
|   `-- syscalls-linux.h
|-- bxversion.h
|-- bxversion.h.in
|-- bxversion.rc
|-- bxversion.rc.in
|-- config.cc
|-- config.guess
|-- config.h
|-- config.h.in
|-- config.log
|-- config.status
|-- config.sub
|-- configure
|-- configure.in
|-- cpu
|   |-- 3dnow.cc
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- Makefile.in
|   |-- access.cc
|   |-- access32.cc
|   |-- access64.cc
|   |-- aes.cc
|   |-- apic.cc
|   |-- apic.h
|   |-- arith16.cc
|   |-- arith32.cc
|   |-- arith64.cc
|   |-- arith8.cc
|   |-- avx.cc
|   |-- avx2.cc
|   |-- avx_fma.cc
|   |-- avx_pfp.cc
|   |-- bcd.cc
|   |-- bit.cc
|   |-- bit16.cc
|   |-- bit32.cc
|   |-- bit64.cc
|   |-- bmi32.cc
|   |-- bmi64.cc
|   |-- call_far.cc
|   |-- cpu.cc
|   |-- cpu.h
|   |-- cpudb
|   |   |-- Makefile
|   |   |-- Makefile.in
|   |   |-- amd_k6_2_chomper.cc
|   |   |-- amd_k6_2_chomper.h
|   |   |-- amd_k6_2_chomper.txt
|   |   |-- athlon64_clawhammer.cc
|   |   |-- athlon64_clawhammer.h
|   |   |-- athlon64_clawhammer.txt
|   |   |-- athlon64_venice.cc
|   |   |-- athlon64_venice.h
|   |   |-- athlon64_venice.txt
|   |   |-- atom_n270.cc
|   |   |-- atom_n270.h
|   |   |-- atom_n270.txt
|   |   |-- core2_penryn_t9600.cc
|   |   |-- core2_penryn_t9600.h
|   |   |-- core2_penryn_t9600.txt
|   |   |-- core_duo_t2400_yonah.cc
|   |   |-- core_duo_t2400_yonah.h
|   |   |-- core_duo_t2400_yonah.txt
|   |   |-- corei5_arrandale_m520.cc
|   |   |-- corei5_arrandale_m520.h
|   |   |-- corei5_arrandale_m520.txt
|   |   |-- corei7_sandy_bridge_2600K.cc
|   |   |-- corei7_sandy_bridge_2600K.h
|   |   |-- corei7_sandy_bridge_2600K.txt
|   |   |-- p2_klamath.cc
|   |   |-- p2_klamath.h
|   |   |-- p2_klamath.txt
|   |   |-- p3_katmai.cc
|   |   |-- p3_katmai.h
|   |   |-- p3_katmai.txt
|   |   |-- p4_prescott_celeron_336.cc
|   |   |-- p4_prescott_celeron_336.h
|   |   |-- p4_prescott_celeron_336.txt
|   |   |-- p4_willamette.cc
|   |   |-- p4_willamette.h
|   |   |-- p4_willamette.txt
|   |   |-- pentium_mmx.cc
|   |   |-- pentium_mmx.h
|   |   `-- pentium_mmx.txt
|   |-- cpuid.h
|   |-- crc32.cc
|   |-- crregs.cc
|   |-- crregs.h
|   |-- ctrl_xfer16.cc
|   |-- ctrl_xfer32.cc
|   |-- ctrl_xfer64.cc
|   |-- ctrl_xfer_pro.cc
|   |-- data_xfer16.cc
|   |-- data_xfer32.cc
|   |-- data_xfer64.cc
|   |-- data_xfer8.cc
|   |-- debugstuff.cc
|   |-- descriptor.h
|   |-- exception.cc
|   |-- fetchdecode.cc
|   |-- fetchdecode.h
|   |-- fetchdecode64.cc
|   |-- fetchdecode_avx.h
|   |-- fetchdecode_sse.h
|   |-- fetchdecode_x87.h
|   |-- fetchdecode_xop.h
|   |-- flag_ctrl.cc
|   |-- flag_ctrl_pro.cc
|   |-- fpu_emu.cc
|   |-- gather.cc
|   |-- generic_cpuid.cc
|   |-- generic_cpuid.h
|   |-- i387.h
|   |-- ia_opcodes.h
|   |-- icache.cc
|   |-- icache.h
|   |-- init.cc
|   |-- instr.h
|   |-- io.cc
|   |-- iret.cc
|   |-- jmp_far.cc
|   |-- lazy_flags.h
|   |-- load.cc
|   |-- logical16.cc
|   |-- logical32.cc
|   |-- logical64.cc
|   |-- logical8.cc
|   |-- mmx.cc
|   |-- msr.cc
|   |-- mult16.cc
|   |-- mult32.cc
|   |-- mult64.cc
|   |-- mult8.cc
|   |-- paging.cc
|   |-- proc_ctrl.cc
|   |-- protect_ctrl.cc
|   |-- resolver.cc
|   |-- ret_far.cc
|   |-- segment_ctrl.cc
|   |-- segment_ctrl_pro.cc
|   |-- shift16.cc
|   |-- shift32.cc
|   |-- shift64.cc
|   |-- shift8.cc
|   |-- simd_compare.h
|   |-- simd_int.h
|   |-- simd_pfp.h
|   |-- smm.cc
|   |-- smm.h
|   |-- soft_int.cc
|   |-- sse.cc
|   |-- sse_move.cc
|   |-- sse_pfp.cc
|   |-- sse_rcp.cc
|   |-- sse_string.cc
|   |-- stack.h
|   |-- stack16.cc
|   |-- stack32.cc
|   |-- stack64.cc
|   |-- string.cc
|   |-- tasking.cc
|   |-- tbm32.cc
|   |-- tbm64.cc
|   |-- todo
|   |-- vm8086.cc
|   |-- vmcs.cc
|   |-- vmexit.cc
|   |-- vmfunc.cc
|   |-- vmx.cc
|   |-- vmx.h
|   |-- xmm.h
|   |-- xop.cc
|   `-- xsave.cc
|-- cpudb.h
|-- crc.cc
|-- disasm
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- Makefile.in
|   |-- dis_decode.cc
|   |-- dis_groups.cc
|   |-- dis_tables.h
|   |-- dis_tables.inc
|   |-- dis_tables_avx.inc
|   |-- dis_tables_sse.inc
|   |-- dis_tables_x87.inc
|   |-- dis_tables_xop.inc
|   |-- disasm.h
|   |-- opcodes.inc
|   |-- resolve.cc
|   `-- syntax.cc
|-- doc
|   |-- docbook
|   |   |-- Makefile
|   |   |-- Makefile.in
|   |   |-- Makefile.jade
|   |   |-- README
|   |   |-- development
|   |   |   `-- development.dbk
|   |   |-- documentation
|   |   |   `-- documentation.dbk
|   |   |-- fixtitles.pl
|   |   |-- images
|   |   |   |-- dlxlinux-in-linux.png
|   |   |   |-- headerbar.png
|   |   |   `-- undercon.png
|   |   |-- include
|   |   |   `-- defs.sgm
|   |   |-- index.html
|   |   |-- misc.txt
|   |   |-- outline.txt
|   |   `-- user
|   |       `-- user.dbk
|   `-- man
|       |-- bochs-dlx.1
|       |-- bochs.1
|       |-- bochsrc.5
|       |-- bxcommit.1
|       `-- bximage.1
|-- docs-html
|   |-- 00README
|   |-- biossums.txt
|   |-- bxdebugger.html
|   |-- cpu_configurability.txt
|   |-- enh_dbg_user_man.txt
|   |-- memory.txt
|   `-- random.txt
|-- extplugin.h
|-- fpu
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- Makefile.in
|   |-- control_w.h
|   |-- f2xm1.cc
|   |-- ferr.cc
|   |-- fpatan.cc
|   |-- fprem.cc
|   |-- fpu.cc
|   |-- fpu_arith.cc
|   |-- fpu_compare.cc
|   |-- fpu_const.cc
|   |-- fpu_constant.h
|   |-- fpu_load_store.cc
|   |-- fpu_misc.cc
|   |-- fpu_tags.cc
|   |-- fpu_trans.cc
|   |-- fsincos.cc
|   |-- fyl2x.cc
|   |-- poly.cc
|   |-- softfloat-compare.h
|   |-- softfloat-macros.h
|   |-- softfloat-muladd.cc
|   |-- softfloat-round-pack.cc
|   |-- softfloat-round-pack.h
|   |-- softfloat-specialize.cc
|   |-- softfloat-specialize.h
|   |-- softfloat.cc
|   |-- softfloat.h
|   |-- softfloat16.cc
|   |-- softfloatx80.cc
|   |-- softfloatx80.h
|   |-- status_w.h
|   |-- tag_w.h
|   `-- todo
|-- gdbstub.cc
|-- gui
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- Makefile.in
|   |-- amigagui.h
|   |-- amigaos.cc
|   |-- bitmaps
|   |   |-- cdromd.h
|   |   |-- cdromd.xpm
|   |   |-- configbutton.h
|   |   |-- configbutton.xpm
|   |   |-- copy.h
|   |   |-- copy.xpm
|   |   |-- floppya.h
|   |   |-- floppya.xpm
|   |   |-- floppyb.h
|   |   |-- floppyb.xpm
|   |   |-- mouse.h
|   |   |-- mouse.xpm
|   |   |-- paste.h
|   |   |-- paste.xpm
|   |   |-- power.h
|   |   |-- power.xpm
|   |   |-- reset.h
|   |   |-- reset.xpm
|   |   |-- saverestore.h
|   |   |-- saverestore.xpm
|   |   |-- snapshot.h
|   |   |-- snapshot.xpm
|   |   |-- userbutton.h
|   |   `-- userbutton.xpm
|   |-- carbon.cc
|   |-- enh_dbg.cc
|   |-- enh_dbg.h
|   |-- font
|   |   `-- vga.bitmap.h
|   |-- gtk_enh_dbg_osdep.cc
|   |-- gui.cc
|   |-- gui.h
|   |-- icon_bochs.h
|   |-- icon_bochs.xpm
|   |-- keymap.cc
|   |-- keymap.h
|   |-- keymaps
|   |   |-- sdl-pc-de.map
|   |   |-- sdl-pc-us.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-be.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-da.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-de.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-es.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-fr.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-it.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-ru.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-se.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-si.map
|   |   |-- x11-pc-uk.map
|   |   `-- x11-pc-us.map
|   |-- macintosh.cc
|   |-- nogui.cc
|   |-- paramtree.cc
|   |-- paramtree.h
|   |-- rfb.cc
|   |-- rfb.h
|   |-- rfbkeys.h
|   |-- sdl.cc
|   |-- sdl.h
|   |-- sdlkeys.h
|   |-- siminterface.cc
|   |-- siminterface.h
|   |-- svga.cc
|   |-- term.cc
|   |-- textconfig.cc
|   |-- textconfig.h
|   |-- wenhdbg_res.h
|   |-- win32.cc
|   |-- win32_enh_dbg_osdep.cc
|   |-- win32dialog.cc
|   |-- win32dialog.h
|   |-- win32paramdlg.cc
|   |-- win32paramdlg.h
|   |-- win32res.h
|   |-- wx.cc
|   |-- wxdialog.cc
|   |-- wxdialog.h
|   |-- wxmain.cc
|   |-- wxmain.h
|   `-- x.cc
|-- host
|   `-- linux
|       `-- pcidev
|           |-- Make.kbuild
|           |-- Makefile
|           |-- Makefile.in
|           |-- kernel_pcidev.h
|           `-- pcidev.c
|-- install-sh
|-- instrument
|   |-- example0
|   |   |-- Makefile.in
|   |   |-- instrument.cc
|   |   `-- instrument.h
|   |-- example1
|   |   |-- Makefile.in
|   |   |-- instrument.cc
|   |   `-- instrument.h
|   |-- example2
|   |   |-- Makefile.in
|   |   |-- instrument.cc
|   |   `-- instrument.h
|   |-- instrumentation.txt
|   `-- stubs
|       |-- Makefile
|       |-- Makefile.in
|       |-- instrument.cc
|       `-- instrument.h
|-- iodev
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- Makefile.in
|   |-- acpi.cc
|   |-- acpi.h
|   |-- aspi-win32.h
|   |-- biosdev.cc
|   |-- biosdev.h
|   |-- busmouse.cc
|   |-- busmouse.h
|   |-- cdrom.cc
|   |-- cdrom.h
|   |-- cdrom_amigaos.cc
|   |-- cdrom_misc.cc
|   |-- cdrom_osx.cc
|   |-- cdrom_win32.cc
|   |-- cmos.cc
|   |-- cmos.h
|   |-- devices.cc
|   |-- devices.txt
|   |-- dma.cc
|   |-- dma.h
|   |-- es1370.cc
|   |-- es1370.h
|   |-- eth_fbsd.cc
|   |-- eth_linux.cc
|   |-- eth_null.cc
|   |-- eth_slirp.cc
|   |-- eth_tap.cc
|   |-- eth_tuntap.cc
|   |-- eth_vde.cc
|   |-- eth_vnet.cc
|   |-- eth_win32.cc
|   |-- extfpuirq.cc
|   |-- extfpuirq.h
|   |-- floppy.cc
|   |-- floppy.h
|   |-- gameport.cc
|   |-- gameport.h
|   |-- harddrv.cc
|   |-- harddrv.h
|   |-- hdimage.cc
|   |-- hdimage.h
|   |-- ioapic.cc
|   |-- ioapic.h
|   |-- iodebug.cc
|   |-- iodebug.h
|   |-- iodev.h
|   |-- keyboard.cc
|   |-- keyboard.h
|   |-- ne2k.cc
|   |-- ne2k.h
|   |-- netmod.cc
|   |-- netmod.h
|   |-- parallel.cc
|   |-- parallel.h
|   |-- pci.cc
|   |-- pci.h
|   |-- pci2isa.cc
|   |-- pci2isa.h
|   |-- pci_ide.cc
|   |-- pci_ide.h
|   |-- pcidev.cc
|   |-- pcidev.h
|   |-- pcipnic.cc
|   |-- pcipnic.h
|   |-- pcivga.cc
|   |-- pcivga.h
|   |-- pic.cc
|   |-- pic.h
|   |-- pit82c54.cc
|   |-- pit82c54.h
|   |-- pit_wrap.cc
|   |-- pit_wrap.h
|   |-- pnic_api.h
|   |-- sb16.cc
|   |-- sb16.h
|   |-- scancodes.cc
|   |-- scancodes.h
|   |-- scsi_commands.h
|   |-- scsi_device.cc
|   |-- scsi_device.h
|   |-- scsidefs.h
|   |-- scsipt.h
|   |-- serial.cc
|   |-- serial.h
|   |-- serial_raw.cc
|   |-- serial_raw.h
|   |-- slowdown_timer.cc
|   |-- slowdown_timer.h
|   |-- soundlnx.cc
|   |-- soundlnx.h
|   |-- soundmod.cc
|   |-- soundmod.h
|   |-- soundosx.cc
|   |-- soundosx.h
|   |-- soundwin.cc
|   |-- soundwin.h
|   |-- speaker.cc
|   |-- speaker.h
|   |-- svga_cirrus.cc
|   |-- svga_cirrus.h
|   |-- unmapped.cc
|   |-- unmapped.h
|   |-- usb_common.cc
|   |-- usb_common.h
|   |-- usb_hid.cc
|   |-- usb_hid.h
|   |-- usb_hub.cc
|   |-- usb_hub.h
|   |-- usb_msd.cc
|   |-- usb_msd.h
|   |-- usb_ohci.cc
|   |-- usb_ohci.h
|   |-- usb_printer.cc
|   |-- usb_printer.h
|   |-- usb_uhci.cc
|   |-- usb_uhci.h
|   |-- usb_xhci.cc
|   |-- usb_xhci.h
|   |-- vga.cc
|   |-- vga.h
|   |-- virt_timer.cc
|   |-- virt_timer.h
|   |-- vmware3.cc
|   |-- vmware3.h
|   |-- vmware4.cc
|   |-- vmware4.h
|   |-- vvfat.cc
|   `-- vvfat.h
|-- libtool
|-- load32bitOShack.cc
|-- logio.cc
|-- ltdl.c
|-- ltdl.h
|-- ltdlconf.h
|-- ltdlconf.h.in
|-- ltmain.sh
|-- main.cc
|-- memory
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- Makefile.in
|   |-- memory.cc
|   |-- memory.h
|   `-- misc_mem.cc
|-- misc
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- Makefile.in
|   |-- bswap.h
|   |-- bxcommit.c
|   |-- bximage.c
|   |-- make_cmos_image.cc
|   |-- niclist.c
|   |-- sb16
|   |   |-- sb16ctrl.c
|   |   |-- sb16ctrl.example
|   |   `-- sb16ctrl.exe
|   |-- spoolpipe.c
|   `-- test-access-check.cc
|-- msrs.def
|-- osdep.cc
|-- osdep.h
|-- param_names.h
|-- patches
|   |-- HEADER
|   |-- NOTES
|   |-- bochs-bios-win32.diff
|   |-- patch.decode-interrupts.gz
|   |-- patch.example-override-ask
|   |-- patch.example-user-plugin
|   |-- patch.fast-dma-cbothamy
|   |-- patch.floppy-athiel
|   |-- patch.hosttime-port
|   |-- patch.marklog
|   `-- patch.mingw-resources
|-- pc_system.cc
|-- pc_system.h
|-- plugin.cc
|-- plugin.h
|-- vs2008
|   |-- bochs.sln
|   |-- bochs.vcproj
|   |-- bx_debug.vcproj
|   |-- bxcommit.vcproj
|   |-- bximage.vcproj
|   |-- cpu.vcproj
|   |-- cpudb.vcproj
|   |-- disasm.vcproj
|   |-- fpu.vcproj
|   |-- gui.vcproj
|   |-- iodev.vcproj
|   |-- memory.vcproj
|   |-- niclist.vcproj
|   `-- stubs.vcproj
|-- win32_enh_dbg.rc
|-- win32res.rc
`-- wxbochs.rc

40 directories, 631 files
```

Comment: Points for a well formatted question. Maybe we don't need to see the complete file tree, but just the items of interest. Anyway, I notice that you have `.../MingW/bin` in your PATH. Is that part of a normal Cygwin install? You might consider installing and switching your project to MingW/Msys for compiling code. Might help to resolve the `check for missing prerequisite headers?` problem. Did you look to see if anything like libiodev.* (dll, so, other?) got created. Have you posted the dev list for bochs? What do they recommend? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter MinGW is part of my Windows `%PATH%` and that's why CygWin also makes it part of CygWin's `$PATH`.

Comment: @shellter It's the first time I build such a big project from source. So I don't really know, which ones the items of interest are.

Comment: @shellter There's nothing with `libiodev` in it's name in Boch's folder or it's descendant folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used mSys instead of CygWin.